# Binding multiple functions to the same event in backbone

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

Is it possible to bind an add event to a collection multiple times. I would like to have multiple functions called when the event fires. ( I have the same collection in several views, so when I add the element I would like addview function of all the views to fire. Right now only the last bounded one fires)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yes, It is possible to have multiple bindings to one event.

if you had:

```
this.model.bind('add', this.add);
this.model.bind('add', this.add2);
```

both add and add2 would run when the add event fired.

Comment: Yup, my bad, when creating a new view I was creating a new collection overwriting the old one so the binding wasn't preserved